# Como Agregar el Atributo ID, mediante Jquery

Tags: jquery

Lo que quiero realizar es generar ID de manera dinámica a través de jquery, ya me lo genera dentro de un for el único problema que tengo con eso es que siempre me deja el ultimo ID que lee y yo quiero que cada ID sea diferentes.

Código donde genera el ID:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var PHP_VARS = <?php echo $planta; ?>;
    for (var i=0; i<PHP_VARS; i++) {
        $(".accordion").append("<li class=tabs><div class=paragraph><h1>Accordion</h1><p>Esto es una Pruba.</p></div></li>")
        $('.tabs').attr('id', 'tabs'+i);
}

$(".accordion").click(function() {
   $(".tabs").css("width","300px"); 
});

});
</script>
```

Codigo HTML:

```
<body id="cuerpo"> 
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="accordion">        
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Has cambiado la pregunta casi por completo mientras te escribía la respuesta

Comment: exacto, lo siento alvaro, es que pense que si generaba los ID manualmente podria ser facil identificar la pulsacion, una disculpa, aparte no pense que alguien me fuera a contestar de esta manera, asi que decidi modificarla. una disculpa

Comment: De todos modos creo que mi respuesta va a seguir solucionando tu problema sin necesidad de ponerle IDs a los tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que presenta la pregunta ahora está aquí:

```
for (var i=0; i<PHP_VARS; i++) {
    $(".accordion").append("<li class=tabs><div class=paragraph><h1>Accordion</h1><p>Esto es una Pruba.</p></div></li>")
    $('.tabs').attr('id', 'tabs'+i);
}
```

Y en concreto en la parte de `$('.tabs').attr('id', 'tabs'+i);`, como estás utilizando un selector bastante genérico y justo después de añadir cada tab, se va a cambiar el ID de todos los tabs en cada pasada del bucle. Por eso acaban siempre con el ID del último.

Para solucionar esto, añade el ID de manera dinámica:

```
for (var i=0; i<PHP_VARS; i++) {
    $(".accordion").append("<li class='tabs' id='tabs" + i + "'><div class='paragraph'><h1>Accordion</h1><p>Esto es una Pruba.</p></div></li>")
}
```

(También he añadido comillas para identificar mejor donde comienza y termina cada campo)

---

El problema está aquí:

```
$(".accordion").click(function() {
   $(".tabs").css("width","300px"); 
});
```

Lo que hace eso es que cuando se pulse sobre un acordeón (`$(".accordion").click(...)`) se va a seleccionar todos los tabs y se va a cambiar el ancho a 300px (`$(".tabs").css("width","300px")`).

Suena correcto, pero no lo es. ¿Por qué? Porque no quieres seleccionar todos los tabs y cambiarles el ancho, quieres sólo los tabs que estén dentro del acordeón pulsado. Eso lo puedes conseguir de este modo:

```
$(".accordion").click(function() {
   $(this).find(".tabs").css("width","300px"); 
});
```

Así se seleccionarán sólo los tabs que estén dentro del acordeón pulsado.

Comment: modifique la pregunta y tambien use tu metodo, pero me sigue marcando la abertura de todos el contendor de tabs.

Comment: Añade el código HTML generado para que podamos ver cómo falla.

Comment: Listo, eh añadido mi estructura de HTML

Comment: @David he editado la pregunta para que cada .tabs tenga id diferente